How to avoid pgfornament being clipped by its bounding box?
Some of the symbols in the pgfornament package render clipped to their bounding box:

This doesn't look like an issue with the vector image itself, as increasing the ornament size decreases the relative clipping. How can I prevent this from happening?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}

\pgfornament[width=.8cm]{3}

\end{document}


Welcome to tex,sx.

This is maybe a bug; you may want to reach out to the pgfornaments author to see what they say.
It is easiest to explain the problem with a picture to start:

The image on the left is of \pgfornament[scale=0.1]{3}, the one on the right is formed by \scalebox{0.1}{\pgfornament{3}}.
As you can clearly see, the two are different.
This is because the image on the left is drawn using \pgftransformscale{...}, which, as explained in this answer changes the coordinates of the curves but keeps the same line width. For many purposes getting a consistent line width provides typographically much more pleasing outputs (and hence I believe that this is intentional). But we get a side effect here.
If you look into the definition of this particular ornament, the ornament is supposed to have, at scale 1, a width of 130bp and height of 65bp. The hard coded bounding rectangle (against which the ornament is clipped) has however coordinates \r -0.3 -0.25 130.25 65.85; which is larger than the declared size of the figure. This is precisely to accommodate the line width at scale 1. When you scale the ornament, the extra bearings gets scaled proportionally, but not the line widths. So when scaling to a scale less than 1, bearings become too small to accommodate the line widths.

If you are bothered more by the clipping than by the thin lines, you can instead of using the scale or width options of \pgfornament, do as I did by rescaling a scale 1 ornament using \scalebox or \resizebox from graphicx. Note that at 0.8cm you are looking at a scale that is approximately 0.15, so the changes to the line widths is quite significant.
A more robust solution would be to reimplement the package so that the clipping rectangle scales differently from the ornament itself. (Basically the clipping rectangle should have coordinates which scale + correction by a non-scaled bearing.) This will require significantly reworking the package.

Edit, a third option
Another option to make the clipping less bad, now that we identify the line width as the culprit: force pgf to draw thinner lines. Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\pgfornament[scale=0.15]{3}
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={ultra thin}}
\pgfornament[scale=0.15]{3}
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={very thin}}
\pgfornament[scale=0.15]{3}
\scalebox{0.15}{\pgfornament{3}}
\end{document}

Output: (at 15% scaling, from left to right we have "original" thickness, line thickness set to "ultra thin", line thickness set to "very thin", and the one coming from rescaling using \scalebox, which would correspond to a line width slightly larger than half of "ultra thin".)

